# Syntax error when $divide & $sum is combined in an aggregation query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Below mongodB Aggregation query is giving a syntax error ':expected' while diving a calculated sum with 65 inside the if statement.There is no issues on the else statement.I guess  brackets are missing somewhere,but i am not able to figure it out.

Can you please help

```
"$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "dailyAccomodationCost": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$eq": ["$currency", 'INR']
                },
                "then": {
                    $divide: [{
                        $sum:
                        [
                            { $multiply: [{ "$avg": "$cost.roomCost" }, 5] },
                            { $multiply: [{ "$avg": "$cost.parkingCost" }, 6] }
                        ], 65}]

                },
                "else": {
                    $sum: [
                        { $multiply: [{ "$avg": "$cost.roomCost" }, 5] },
                        { $multiply: [{ "$avg": "$cost.parkingCost" }, 6] }
                    ]
                }``
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "divide" array 65 should be between } and ] if you want to divide by 65. 
Now it is not valid json.

```
"$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "dailyAccomodationCost": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$eq": ["$currency", 'INR']
                },
                "then": {
                    $divide: [{
                        $sum:
                        [
                            { $multiply: [{ "$avg": "$cost.roomCost" }, 5] },
                            { $multiply: [{ "$avg": "$cost.parkingCost" }, 6] }
                        ]}, 65]

                },
                "else": {
                    $sum: [
                        { $multiply: [{ "$avg": "$cost.roomCost" }, 5] },
                        { $multiply: [{ "$avg": "$cost.parkingCost" }, 6] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```